# Visual C# - Associate event handler with CellDoubleClick event

Tags: c#, datagridview, overloading

I'm working in visual studio and trying to get information from a DataGridView cell when the user double clicks on it.  I basically set up the CellDoubleClick event just like any other Click event but that doesn't seem to work.

Code:

Form1.cs

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "ColumnIndex", e.ColumnIndex);
        messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
        messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "RowIndex", e.RowIndex);
        messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
        MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "CellDoubleClick Event");
    }
```

Pertinent code in Form1.Designer.cs

```
this.dataGridView1.CellDoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick);
```

I am getting an error in the Form1.Designer code that says, "No overload for 'dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'.

How can I get the double click to work correctly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CellDoubleClick` event is a `DataGridViewCellEventHandler`, not an 
EventHandler`.

You should add the event handles using the designer, which will automatically use the correct delegate type.
You should not edit the designer-generated code manually.

In general, when adding event handlers, you shouldn't explicitly create the delegate.
Instead, you can write

```
myGrid.CellDoubleClick += MyGrid_CellDoubleClick;
```

Comment: Ok, I'm not terribly good at Visual Studio and I was kind of at my wits end trying to get double click to work.  After I read your comment I looked closer at the designer and found the events button.  Now it works.  Thanks.

Comment: If you have time , please explain to me as if i were 5 years old why it's not possible to simply do += new EventHandler(MyGrid_CellDoubleClick); to handle this event, i do not get it. :)

Comment: @JazzCat: Because that event is declared as a different type. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171