# how to add a EventHandler to a DataGrid button where the button is added dynamiclly based on a database?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

So i successfully dynamiclly add button on DataGridView (DataGridViewButtonColumn) based on tables count in my database with :

```
//'cmd' type is MySqlCommand and 'cnnct' is MySqlConnection
//this is inside the Main()
string cmdString = "SHOW TABLES";
cmd.CommandText = cmdString;
cmd.Connection = cnnct;
Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
       {
           classSelect.Rows.Add(Reader.GetString(0));
       }
Reader.Close();
```

then i've prepared a method that will be called when the button is clicked.

```
protected internal void FormCaller (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //There's should be unique ID for the 'sender', but i don't know how
        if(aioForm == null)
        {
            //'AIO_Form' is a Form
            splash.ShowSplashScreen();
            aioForm = new AIO_Form(this);
            splash.CloseForm();
            this.Visible = false;
            aioForm.Visible = true;
        }
        //and some other code, handling if aioForm isn't null
    }
```

The problem is, how i can add an EventHandler to the dynamiclly generated button, and it is based on a remote database ?

i've read from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252238/visual-c-sharp-associate-event-handler-with-celldoubleclick-event) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577297/how-to-handle-click-event-in-button-column-in-datagridview) (both are from StackOverflow) but no help.

Thanks in advance everybody.

Comment: Where is the code that add the button dynamically?

Comment: as i remember method Add() returns the instance of added row, so you can subscribe to Click event.

Comment: ASP.NET or Winforms? `DataGridView` is Winforms control, `DataGrid` ASP.NET

Comment: @GhyathSerhal : The first code snippet, after `while`
@Fabio : It is WinForm, i'll edit that
@EugeneKotov : So how i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days do this and that, i can provide a workaround. Despite add the EventHandler to the Cell i add it to the DataGrid itself, then the Method which Handle the event should identify the cell that raise the event

add the EventHandler

```
while (Reader.Read())
{
    var Name = UppercaseWords(Reader.GetString(0));
    kelasSelect.Rows.Add(Name);
}
Reader.Close();
classSelect.CellMouseUp += FormCaller;
```

Then ***FormCaller*** which handle the event

```
protected internal void FormCaller(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataGridView Sender = (DataGridView)sender;
   string FormName = Sender.CurrentCell.Value.ToString(); //This is how i identify the cell who raise the event
   NForm = new myForm(this);
   NForm.Text = FormName;
}
```